# Replacing delete button with restore depending on boolean value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have boolean column named "deleted" in mysql.
1)if the row is not deleted it shows the delete button.
2)if the row is deleted it should display retore button in that datagrid cell instead of deleted with the query of restore behind it.

right now i can only disable the button if the row is deleted.

My code is as follows.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Delete" Name="btnDelete" 
                            Click="btnDelete_Click">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">

                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding deleted}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"  />


                                            </DataTrigger>

                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is using converter that will convert bool value to visibility.

However, for restore button, you will need to invert the visibility behavior, therefore custom converter comes in mind

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool boolValue))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        if (parameter == null || (parameter is bool invertVisibility && !invertVisibility))
            return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return boolValue ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then your buttons will use the same converter registered as:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"></local:BoolToVisibilityConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

But one of them will pass additional parameter so that converter will invert its logic:

```
<Button Margin="5" Content="Delete" 
        Visibility="{Binding deleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"></Button>
<Button Margin="5" Content="Restore" 
        Visibility="{Binding deleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding RestoreCommand}"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in BoolToVisibilityConverter and set the Visibility Property, you might not need a trigger for this

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleIfTrueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...

 <Button Visibility={Binding deleted, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}/>
```